# Write a line in php

Tags: php, html

I want to write a php code in totally php syntax. The html code should also be written in php.
I am trying so hard to write this but failed. Anybody help in this problem. Please tell me the write syntax immediately. Note that: base_url and slugify are functions. Please look at this code now. I make it more easier that you could understand now

```
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) 
{ 
$htmlmsg=htmlentities($row['Name']); //HTML entries filter
//$msg .= "<li><b>" . $row['Sku'] . "</b> " . $htmlmsg . "</li>";
$msg .= "<div class='deal'><div class='deal-left'>
        <img src=".$row["ImageURL"]." width='100px'/>
    </div>
    <div class='deal-right'>
//------- I want below line in correct syntan of php. Right Now is not a right syntax.
        <h2><a href='base_url'deals/'slugify".$row['Merchant']."'/'slugify".$row['Name']."'/'".$row['id']."'>".substr($row['Name'], 0,50)."</a></h2>
//--------
        <div class='deal-info'>SKU</div>
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What are you getting at?

Comment: And the *problem* with this line is...?

Comment: is `base_url` a defined constant or you forgot a `$`?

Comment: base_url and slugify are functions, i write it myself

Comment: There is not any problem with this line, I just want to write this line in totally php. Guys please sort it .

Comment: are you want to create another php file from this php code. I think you want this code show in another php file?

Comment: escape quotes with \ not with /

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<a href="'.base_url.'deals/'.slugify($row['Merchant']).'/'.slugify($row['Name']).'/'.$row['id'].'">'.substr($row['Name'], 0,33).'...</a></h2>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it helps to break things up into different parts for readability. You can also try using a framework like [Slim PHP](http://www.slimframework.com) for separating your business logic from your presentation layer. Please watch this code again and then correct it according to my need please.

```
<?php
   $url = base_url('deals/' . slugify($row['Merchant']) . 
        '/' . slugify($row['Name']) . $row['id'] );
?>
<h2>
   <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo substr($row['Name'], 0,33); ?></a>
</h2>
```

One line of php code (although ugly IMO):

```
 <?php
  echo '<a href="' . base_url('deals/' . slugify($row['Merchant']) . '/' . slugify($row['Name']) . $row['id']) . '">' . substr($row['Name'], 0,33) . '</a>';
 ?>
```

Comment: it looks like there is a missing `)` in your code ( `base_url(` never closed)

Comment: Thx, I corrected the mistype.

Comment: @ZainAbid Don't change my answer simply because you edited your question then inform me to watch for your changes. Nobody is going to write all of your code for you...

Answer (score 0):

would be better if you wrappend your html code in php 
For example
Instead of

```
<h1><a href="<?php echo base_url.deals>
```

Write

```
<?php echo"<h1>"."<a href='linkdiscription'>";
```

This would be better

Comment: Imho this is more error prone and harder to read, and OP doesn't need some more quoted string like errors

Answer (score 0):

> I want to write a php code in totally php syntax. The html code should
>   also be written in php.

```
<?php
$row['Merchant'] = 'Merchant';
$row['Name']     = 'Name';
$row['id']       = 'Id';

echo chr(60).chr(104).chr(50).chr(62).chr(60).
     chr(97).chr(32).chr(104).chr(114).chr(101).
     chr(102).chr(61).chr(34).chr(100).
     chr(101).chr(97).chr(108).chr(115).chr(47).
     $row['Merchant'].chr(47).$row['Name'].chr(47).
     $row['id'].chr(34).chr(62).chr(32).
     substr($row['Name'],0,33).chr(46).chr(46).
     chr(46).chr(32).chr(60).chr(47).chr(97).
     chr(62).chr(60).chr(47).chr(104).chr(50).chr(62);
?>
```

http://codepad.org/9zXlGbzW

Sorry I couldn't help myself...;p